# Are React Server Components appropriate to fetch a partial page based on client state?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-server-components

I'm writing a [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) 14 [App Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app) application. I want to display a 'popup' component in a [`react-map-gl`](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/) marker `onClick` handler. The 'info box' popup content needs to change based on the marker selected, via a database lookup.

[React Server Components](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components) feel like the right way to do this now, but they only render once. This can be circumvented by invalidating with [`revalidatePath`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations), but that seems to to re-render the whole page. I don't want to redraw my map, just the 'info box' component.

Various examples show database changes, followed by a reload of the same data (with additions now present in the database). That works if the change is in the database table, but not if I want to change the database query.

I want to change what I'm querying the database for (a `WHERE slug = input` clause). So I need to pass client state changes to the server, which doesn't seem possible.

It looks like I need to use [Server Actions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations) instead. Am I wide of the the mark?

Answer (score 0):

[reactjs/server-components-demo](https://github.com/reactjs/server-components-demo/) described in [React Labs: What We've Been Working On – March 2023](https://github.com/reactjs/server-components-demo/blob/95fcac10102d20722af60506af3b785b557c5fd7/server/api.server.js#L109) appears to do what I'm after, but it seems to do so by hoisting the state above the `App` component [main/src/App.js](https://github.com/reactjs/server-components-demo/blob/main/src/App.js):

```js
export default function App({selectedId, isEditing, searchText}) {
  return (
    ...
    <Note selectedId={selectedId} isEditing={isEditing} />
    ...
  );
}
```

State is provided by [server/api.server.js#L109](https://github.com/reactjs/server-components-demo/blob/95fcac10102d20722af60506af3b785b557c5fd7/server/api.server.js#L109):

```js
 renderReactTree(res, {
    selectedId: location.selectedId,
    isEditing: location.isEditing,
    searchText: location.searchText,
  });
```

I'm not sure if that is possible in a standard Next.js App router project.